# Perl testing wrapper around production script

Tags: perl, testing, wrapper, diagnostics, aspect

For testing purposes I want to create a wrapping script that can add functionality to an existing script without changing the original script. My question is, is this possible in perl and how do I do it?

The wrapper script would do things like:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;
use Aspect;

run syntax checking on config files;
run unittesting stuff;
call production script;
```

The production script would be unchanged and be entirely standalone:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

bunch of production code here;
```

Of course I want the diagnostics and aspect weaving to work on the production code. I already tried some simple things and they didn't work, code didn't even run.

```
eval { require "production.pl" };
do 'production.pl';
require 'production.pl';
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use [Test::Script::Run](http://search.cpan.org/~sunnavy/Test-Script-Run-0.08/lib/Test/Script/Run.pm). The blocks helps you to separate the test cases.

You could call your program this way to get diagnostic messages:

```
perl -Mdiagnostics -MAspect your_script.pl [args]
```

This how you could integrate this test:

```
use Test::More;
use Test::Script::Run;
### test 1
{
  note 'test1 is running...';
  note 'test 1 app_name running fine';
  run_ok( 'app_name', [ app's args ], 'app_name runs ok' );
  note 'test 1 does not throws errors and returns correct values';
  my ( $return, $stdout, $stderr ) = run_script( 'app_name', [ app's args ] );
  run_output_matches_unordered(
        'app_name', [ app's args ],
        [ 'out line 2', 'out line 1' ],
        [ 'err line 2', 'err line 1' ],
        'run_output_matches_unordered'
  );

};
### test 2
{
   ...
};
done_testing();
```

Comment: I ran a test but the diagnostics does not get applied to the production script if you call it this way. Run uses IPC::Run3 in the background which seems to just spawn a separate process. The imports from the caller are then not applied to the callee.

Comment: That is a very different thing. You could achive that this way:
perl -Mdiagnostics -MAspect your_script.pl [args]